# How do i pass my chatroom id to my ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to call the id when user select different room. different have different id so how i let ajax know which room i have enter?

and i have use ajax call two function php
which is

- chatNew.php for insert message
- chatMessage.php for load message

i have used `$chatroomID =$_GET['chatroomID'];`
to call the id but seem no working and get an error

-localhost/pme/main/chatroom.php?chatroomID=1 << how i get the chatroomID

here is chatrooms.php i have use sql statement select all the chatroom out from database

```
 <td>
        <a onclick="poll" href="chatroom.php?chatroomID=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
            <div>
                <p>
                    <?php echo ($row['name']); ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
```

This is my js file

```
function submitChat(){
        var message = chatroom.message.value;
    if(chatroom.message.value == ''){
        alret('You didnt input any message');
        return;
    }

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET','chatNew.php?&message='+message,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    $('.chatroom-message-container').scrollTop($('.chatroom-message-container').get(0).scrollHeight);
}

$(document).ready(function(e){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function(){$('#inner').load('chatMessage.php');}, 2000);

    $(".sendmessage-btn").click(function(){
        $("#area-message").val('');     
    });  
});

(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"chatRoom.php?chatroomID=id", 
            success:function(data)
            {
                setValue(data.value);
            },
            dataType:"json",
            complete:poll
        });
    },
    30000
            );  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax data option to send variable and you can get on chatRoom.php by PHP GET.

```
(function poll() {
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"chatRoom.php", 
        data:{chatroomID:id},
        success:function(data)
        {
            setValue(data.value);
        },
        dataType:"json",
        complete:poll
    });
},30000);  
});
```

Comment: i have found another way to do but still thanks for you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter to your poll function with the submit button like this

```
<button onclick="poll('<?php echo $id; ?>')">send</button>

(function poll(id) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"chatRoom.php?chatroomID="+id, 
                success:function(data)
                {
                    setValue(data.value);
                },
                dataType:"json",
                complete:poll
            });
        },
        30000
        );  
 });
```

Comment: i have found another way to do but still thanks for you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to change..

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','chatNew.php?&message='+message,true);
```

.. to include the `chatroomID`:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','chatNew.php?message=' + message + '&chatroomID=<?php echo $row['id'];?>', true);
```